# React - Add chart to exported excel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, kendo-ui

I'm looking for a way to add a chart to my excel file that is generated by a react app (the kind of chart that you can insert normally in MS Excel and is dependent on some cell values, not an image of a chart)

currently I'm using Kendo-UI to export excel, but I'm open to changing it to any other library that also works fine with excel formats and styles,

this is an example of the result I need:

[image: example]

**any recommendation or workaround is appreciated**

**ps**: the number of rows containing data may change each time

Comment: Make a template with the chart etc set up, and then paste the data into place and save as.

Comment: how can I do that? the main problem is that I can't find the setup to add the chart

Comment: Well, looks like you have done it - just take the file you have and delete the data and save as a template. Then call the template from the other program...

Comment: @SolarMike I haven't done it using react, I did it in excel, can you explain more?

Comment: You have the file in excel, save as template... Can't see what else I have to explain.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm making the excel file using kendo ui, just passing the data and formats and it generates the file, how can I pass a template to it? should I use another way? can an excel file be generated using vanilla javascript? there should not be any human work for making the file, the file should be generated only using react or pure javascript